# Add new rows to pandas dataframe with reference with other Row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

df:

```
End_Dt_Id Start_Date     End_Date
18AUG19   12-08-2019    18-08-2019  -- date format DD/MM/YYYY
25AUG19   19-08-2019    25-08-2019
01SEP19   26-08-2019    01-09-2019
08SEP19   02-09-2019    08-09-2019
15SEP19   09-09-2019    15-09-2019
22SEP19   16-09-2019    22-09-2019
12SEP19   23-09-2019    29-09-2019
```

I need to add 4 more weeks to my dataframe which will depend upon last week in my df,
for example the last week would be this row "29SEP19   23-09-2019   29-09-2019" because of max(End_Date), there after i need to add four more weeks as shown in the output.

df_output:

```
End_Dt_Id Start_Date     End_Date
18AUG19   12-08-2019    18-08-2019  -- date format DD/MM/YYYY
25AUG19   19-08-2019    25-08-2019
01SEP19   26-08-2019    01-09-2019
08SEP19   02-09-2019    08-09-2019
15SEP19   09-09-2019    15-09-2019
22SEP19   16-09-2019    22-09-2019
29SEP19   23-09-2019    29-09-2019
05OCT19   30-09-2019    05-10-2019
12OCT19   06-10-2019    12-10-2019
19OCT19   13-10-2019    19-10-2019
26OCT19   20-10-2019    26-10-2019
```

Comment: wouldn't the max end date be `22-09-2019`?  Or are you just looking to add 4 rows the last row?

Comment: why are your dates going backwards, whats the logic here?

Comment: @Datanovice sorry my bad, I have corrected the question please look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the logic, but this provides the output you are looking for:

```
last_row = df.sort_values('End_Date')[-1:]
new_rows = []
start_date = last_row['Start_Date'].iloc[0]
end_date = last_row['End_Date'].iloc[0]
for i in range(1,5):

    start_date = end_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    end_date = end_date + dt.timedelta(days=7)
    end_dt_id = dt.datetime.strftime(end_date, '%d%b%y').upper()
    new_rows.append([end_dt_id,start_date, end_date])
    
df = pd.concat([
    df, 
    pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=['End_Dt_Id', 'Start_Date', 'End_Date'])
])
for col in ['Start_Date', 'End_Date']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Returns:

```
End_Dt_Id  Start_Date    End_Date
  18AUG19  12-08-2019  18-08-2019
  25AUG19  19-08-2019  25-08-2019
  01SEP19  26-08-2019  01-09-2019
  08SEP19  02-09-2019  08-09-2019
  15SEP19  09-09-2019  15-09-2019
  22SEP19  16-09-2019  22-09-2019
  12SEP19  23-09-2019  12-09-2019
  19SEP19  13-09-2019  19-09-2019
  26SEP19  20-09-2019  26-09-2019
  03OCT19  27-09-2019  03-10-2019
  10OCT19  04-10-2019  10-10-2019
```

Comment: sorry my bad, I have corrected the question please look into it.

Comment: I don't understand the logic.. the values in the first dataframe increment by 7.. for example, `15-09-2019 - > 22-09-2019`.. but there are only 6 days between `29-09-2019` and `05-10-2019`

Comment: Actually I got the logic part, but one thing is to worry about, df not alway contain the last row as max(date) row , so df[-1] won't always work. So it would be good to fetch last row based on dates..

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer to grab the last row by date

Comment: i have a doubt, how start date and end date is changing because you wrote start_date = end_date + dt.timedelta(days=1) so it should give 30-06-2019 if my       last_row['end_date'] = 29-06-2019 for the 1 first iteration. And for the second iteration since the end date is referring from  last_row, again it should give 30-06-2019 but it would give you 07-07-2019 how???

Comment: Where did it give me `07-07-2019`?

Comment: And why would the last row end date be `29-06-2019`? That isn't anywhere in the data frame you provided

Comment: Lets suppose,.                                              last_row = 12SEP19  06-09-2019  12-09-2019.              my start_date is 06-09-2019 and end_date is 12-09-2019 as per last_row.        so for first iteration start_date would be 13-09-2019 and end_date would be 19-09-2019 which I understand. What my question is, since start_date and end end_referring from last_row, for the second iteration the start_date and end_date would be same as in the 1st iteration. But it is giving 20-09-2019 and 26-09-2019, I wanted to know how this is coming, though it is correct as per my question.

Comment: The first iteration is the only one that refers to the last_row. This is because `start_date` and `end_date` are redefined after each iteration.